# Group By attribute.model possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I currently have something like this working:

```
period_registration = PeriodRegistration.count(:conditions => ["created_at >= ?", 30.days.ago.to_date], group: "date(created_at)")
```

but, I want to do something like this:

```
 period_registration_product = PeriodRegistration.count(:conditions => ["created_at >= ?", 30.days.ago.to_date], group: "period_id.product")
```

When I do this, I get nothing back in period_registration_product. What's the best way to sort by product when I have a product_id in my Period_Registration model?

Update:

`@period_registration_product = PeriodRegistration.joins(:period).where("date(created_at) >= ?", 30.days.ago.to_date).group("periods.product_id").count`

results in:

`SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: created_at: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, periods.product_id AS periods_product_id FROM "period_registrations" INNER JOIN "periods" ON "periods"."id" = "period_registrations"."period_id" WHERE (date(created_at) >= '2012-07-25') GROUP BY periods.product_id`

Do I need to specify which created_at, I want to look at `period` or `period_registration`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query

```
PeriodRegistration.joins(:period).where("period_registrations.created_at >= ?", 30.days.ago.to_date).group("periods.product_id").count
```

This will return a hash of how many objects are in each product_id

Comment: This doesn't work, because I have a period_id, not a product_id. If I were to chain them all together it would go `period_registration.period.product_id`

Comment: above you said "product_id in my Period_Registration model" so I was confused. You will probably need to join the tables, I will update my answer.

Comment: you can try changing it to where("period_registrations.created_at >= ?", 30.days.ago.to_date)

Comment: That error goes away, but there is nothing in my `period_registration_product`

Comment: Can you post the SQL  query and are you trying this out in your rails console?

Comment: It helps if you actually have populated your database :)